# In a directed graph, every vertex has exactly seven edges coming in. What can one always say about the number of edges going out of its vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

1.Exactly seven edges leave every vertex.

2.Exactly seven edges leave some vertex.

3.Some vertex has at least seven edges leaving it.

4.The number of edges coming out of vertex is odd.

I am unable to approach this question , both option 2 and 3 seem correct to me ,How should I check which one is correct ?

Comment: For each one, try to find a reason why it might be true, and simultaneously try to find a counter-example.

Comment: And always try small cases.. perhaps "seven" is not relevant?

Comment: For me both 2 and 3rd option seem to be correct

Comment: Did you try small cases or not? Why should you try for only "seven" and not for "one" and "two" and "three" first to get an idea of the structure of the problem?

Comment: I think you can solve this just by remembering that the total sum of the indegrees (in this case 7*n, where n is the number of nodes) must equal the total sum of the outdegrees. BTW, in 4), did you mean "some vertex" or "all vertexes"?